# Snowpipe: Importing historical data that may be modified without causing re-imports

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

To start with, I'm not sure if this is possible with the existing features of Snowpipe.

I have a S3 bucket with years of data, and occasionally some of those files get updated (the contents change, but the file name stays the same). I was hoping to use Snowpipe to import these files into Snowflake, as the "we won't reimport files that have been modified" aspect is appealing to me.

However, I discovered that `ALTER PIPE ... REFRESH` can only be used to import files staged no earlier than seven days ago, and the only other recommendation Snowflake's documentation has for importing historical data is to use `COPY INTO ...`. *However*, if I use that, then if those old files get modified, they get imported via Snowflake since the metadata preventing `COPY INTO ...` from re-importing the S3 files and the metadata for Snowpipe are different, so I can end up with that file imported twice.

Is there any approach, short of "modify *all* those files in S3 so they have a recent modified-at timestamp", that would let me use Snowpipe with this?

Comment: ALTER PIPE...REFRESH also would only load files that have not already been loaded.  It is meant to fix short-term issues, not handle a routine production pattern. I am slightly confused by your ask, though.  Do you want the files that are modified to be reloaded or not?

Comment: I want the files that are modified to _not_ be reloaded. I would only be using `ALTER PIPE ... REFRESH` just once, to ingest any data from the past that Snowpipe won't pick up.

Comment: I see, so the concern is that those files may be older than 7 days and you want to find a way for ALTER PIPE ... REFRESH to find them?  Do you know which files need to be loaded that were missed?

Comment: Either I would like `ALTER PIPE ... REFRESH` to find them, so that if they get edited in the future, Snowpipe won't re-ingest them, or some other approach that results in the same situation with Snowpipe.

From my understanding of the documentation, `ALTER PIPE ... REFRESH` only takes the last seven days' worth of staged files, so I want to load everything before then (say from Jan 1, 2018 to seven days ago, for instance).

Comment: I have just 1 more question, because I'm not sure Snowpipe is really the right tool for what you want to do.  Your S3 bucket that contains historical data that occasionally get updated....is that a data lake that is leveraged directly and updated by something else?  Is it possible for you to move files once they are loaded into Snowflake?  There are a lot of solutions to your problem, and I just want to make sure I offer up one that suits your environment.

Comment: Currently, we archive rows from one of our traditional database's tables to the S3 bucket, and then we run a scheduled job that uses `MERGE INTO ...` to import from that bucket to a Snowflake table. The S3 bucket serves as a backup of data from all time since the source table is regularly truncated. It would be possible to modify our archival process so it writes to both a S3 backup bucket as well as a "S3 Snowpipe ingest bucket", and then move files in that latter bucket.

Comment: If the goal is to keep your Snowflake table in-sync with your source table, you could also consider using an external table to the files in the S3 bucket, and then either use that directly, or MERGE INTO your snowflake table from the external table.  This would avoid Snowpipe altogether, but if your S3 files change, the external table would, as well.

Comment: An external table does make sense since we need to keep the table in sync, although it seems like we wouldn't be able to use the table directly since even with partitioning, the external table's scan performance can be pretty poor (a query that scans 2 GB of data in the Snowflake table has to scan 32 GB in the external table). I haven't tested using `MERGE INTO`, but my initial guess is that it would take too long, so our current approach (`MERGE INTO ...` from the stage to Snowflake table, with a separate task to delete data infrequently) might be the best we can get at this point.

Comment: It is also possible to create a materialized view over your external table, which make it perform as if it were a table.  You'd have to weigh the costs (both storage and compute costs) of the materialized view against the costs of merging into an actual table.

Comment: External tables + materialized views actually does sound like a much cleaner solution– I don't think I have materialized views enabled at the moment, but I'll have to test that out when I get a chance, thanks!

Comment: When you figure it out, come back and put your answer into the Answer section, so people can find it.  Lots of options, but it is certainly a unique scenario.

Comment: Why not post an answer with the conclusion from these comments? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to a scripting solution for this, one solution would be to write a script to pull the set of in scope object names from AWS S3 and feed them to the Snowpipes REST API. The code you'd use for this is very similar to what is required if you're using an AWS Lambda to call the Snowpipe REST API when triggered via an S3 event notification. You can either use the AWS SDK to get the set of objects from S3, or just use Snowflake's [LIST STAGE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/list.html) statement to pull them.

I've used this approach multiple times to backfill historical data from an AWS S3 location where we've enabled Snowpipe ingestion after data had already been written there. Even in the scenario where you don't have to worry about a file being updated in place, this can still be an advantage over just falling back to a direct COPY INTO because you don't have to worry if there's any overlap between when the PIPE was first enabled and the set of files you push to the Snowpipe REST API since the PIPE load history will take care of that for you..